# Sitecore: Unable to get to login screen

Tags: sitecore

I'm new to Sitecore. We are in the process of implementing Sitecore and currently wanted to test Sitecore CMS on Windows 10 laptop. Everything has been installed as prompted but I'm not able to get to the login screen. It only displays sitecore image on it. Not sure, if there is some settings that needs to be done on IIS or etc. I have also edited the host file and used 127.0.0.1 NewInstance1 and user SC User has been added to the database.

Here's the environment:

Windows 10 Pro
SQL Server 2012 Express
Sitecore 7.2 CMS
IIS (default version, not sure if it's express)

Any help shall be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the latest 7.2? for compatibility Sitecore 7.2 Update-4 introduced Windows 10 support for CMS and DMS 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://localhost/sitecore/

login is admin, password is b